# Me sale el Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php, html

Tengo un programa a manera de practicar mis conocimientos en php y BD, sin embargo no he podido solucionar lo siguiente:

Busco preguntar a la base de datos que cuanto tenga valores me traiga el nombre del usuario y lo ponga en el input, pero sino tiene valores o no existe ese id, que el input lo deje vacio.

Estuve leyendo que cuando se cumple la primera condicion es porque viene en forma de arreglo, pero cuando la consulta no encuentra valores me trae un FALSE, por lo que sale ese warning.

Dejo el codigo que me funciona solo en la primera condición, pero la segunda no logro hacer que solo me muestre el input vacio sin ese mensaje warning.

```
<?php

$item = "id";
$valor = $_GET["idHisClinica"];
$seguimientoClinico = ControladorHistoriasClinicas::ctrMostrarSeguimientosClinicos($item, $valor);
     
$itemUsuario = "id";
$valorUsuario = $seguimientoClinico["id_usuario"];
$usuario = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($itemUsuario, $valorUsuario);

if($seguimientoClinico["folio_seguimiento"] >= 1){

 echo '<input type="text" class="form-control Poppins" value="'.$usuario["nombre"].'" readonly>';

}else{

  echo '<input type="text" class="form-control Poppins" readonly>';

}

?>
```

Agradeceria mucho de su ayuda, si pudiera asesorarme.

Comment: Error completo dentro de la pregunta, por favor. La puedes [edit]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Valida primero si el arreglo **$seguimientoClinico** trae datos usando la función `!empty()`. Si trae datos haces la siguiente consulta, validas el nuevo arreglo y asignas el nombre de usuario a la variable, en caso contrario la variable seguirá estando vacía.

Al final solo será necesario un `echo` que mostrará el valor de la variable, esté o no vacía.

```
<?php
  $item = "id";
  $valor = $_GET["idHisClinica"];
  $seguimientoClinico = 
  ControladorHistoriasClinicas::ctrMostrarSeguimientosClinicos($item, $valor);

  $nombreUsuario = '';

  if(!empty($seguimientoClinico)){
    $itemUsuario = "id";
    $valorUsuario = $seguimientoClinico["id_usuario"];
    $usuario = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($itemUsuario, $valorUsuario);
    $nombreUsuario = !empty($usuario) ? $usuario["nombre"] : '';
  }
 echo '<input type="text" class="form-control Poppins" value="'.$nombreUsuario.'" readonly>';
?>
```

En caso de que se siga presentando el error, verifica los datos que te están llegando con `var_dump($seguimientoClinico);`

Comment: Me funcionó correctamente a lo que necesitaba. MUCHAS GRACIAS! Ahora estudiare esta parte del codigo.

Comment: @Edgar, si te funcionó la respuesta, márcala como aceptada ✔ y vota por ella. Es la manera de mostrar aprecio por la ayuda y de permitir a otros que lleguen aquí con tu mismo problema saber que la respuesta es efectiva.